# Jquery, any thoughts how to not repeat the code here?

Tags: jquery, html, repeat

I use this to make the menu work for my gallery. The .masonry # are on display:none, this way i can use the ID in the menu to show the appropriate gallery when clicked.
A lot of code is repeated. Hoping somebody has a good solution that takes away the repeating. If possible.

```
$(function() {

  $( "#vakantie" ).click(function() {
    $(".masonry").hide(400)
    $( "#travel" ).show( "fade", 1250 );
  });


  $( "#mensen" ).click(function() {
    $(".masonry").hide(400)
    $( "#people" ).show( "fade", 1250 );
  });


  $( "#dieren" ).click(function() {
    $(".masonry").hide(400)
    $( "#animal" ).show( "fade", 1250 );
  });

  $( "#bloemen" ).click(function() {
    $(".masonry").hide(400)
    $( "#corso" ).show( "fade", 1250 );
  });

  $( "#event" ).click(function() {
    $(".masonry").hide(400)
    $( "#eventGallery" ).show( "fade", 1250 );
  });

});
```

Comment: Is there any relation between the element you click on, and the element you want to show based on that? Specific HTML structure, ...? Show us your HTML as well.

Comment: if you share html then may be you will get some solution otherwise not possible at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a common `class` to all buttons, for example 'my-button'

```
$('body').on('click','.my-button',function(){
    // .. then check the id
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(".masonry").hide(400);

   //..apply condition
    if(id == 'vakantie'){
        $('#travel').show( "fade", 1250 );
    }else if(id == 'mensen'){
        $('#people').show( "fade", 1250 );
    }
        //..etc so on.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data-` attributes to link buttons and content.  Click a button, read its data- (eg data-link) then find the element in the data-link and show that.

This has the benefit that your code does not need to change when you add/remove buttons/panels and is not reliant on parsing IDs.

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
  var panel = $(this).data("link");
  //console.log(panel)
  $(".panel").hide(function() {
    $("div[data-link='" + panel + "']").fadeIn(1250);
  });
});
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='link' data-link='travel'>vakentie</button>
<button class='link' data-link='people'>mensen</button>
<div class='panel' data-link='travel'>Travel</div>
<div class='panel' data-link='people'>People</div>
```

Comment: Hi it worked, using the other method above cause i do not fully understand yours yet. Looking in the Jquery API on .data and data-links.

Comment: That's ok, learning is iterative.  You start with your distinct one-for-one method (click A do A, click B do B) then the accepted answer is the next step (click A or B, do A or B based on what was clicked)  @TetrisTyp's answer would be the next iteration where you move the pairing click/do into an array so that the data and code are separate which makes it more maintainable and then the next step would be this one where you completely separate data from code.  There's no doubt another iteration after this where you might use angular or something to remove some of the code (fully data driven).

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to slightly change the names of your id's, to start with a specific prefix (id='xx_bloemen', id='xx_mensen', id='xx_dieren', and so on).
Then in your code:

```
$('div[id^="xx_"]').click(function() {
  $(".masonry").hide(400);
});
```

It wil be used for every div with an id starting with 'xx_'.
You might need some additional quotes somewhere in this example (I've done this by heart), but I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  var $vakantie = $('#vakantie'),
      $mensen = $('#mensen'),
      $dieren = $('#dieren'),
      $bloemen = $('#bloemen'),
      $masonry = $('.masonry'),
      $travel = $('#travel');

  function handleClick() {
    $masonry.hide(400)
    $trave.show('fade', 1250 );
  }

  Array.prototype.forEach.call([$akantie, $mensen, $dieren, $bloemen], 
    function (node) {
      $(node).on('click', handleClick);
    }
  );

});
```

or create one class like `js-fade-in-out` and bind an event just to this one class.

Basically you want to pass one event handler if it's the same for every element.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, short and effective. You only have to specify your menu.

```
$(function() {
    var menu = [
      ['vakantie', 'travel'],
      ['mensen', 'people']
    ];
    menu.forEach(function(element) {
        $( "#"+element[0] ).click(function() {
                $(".masonry").hide(400);
                $( "#"+element[1] ).show( "fade", 1250 );
        });
    });
});
```